# Django - 301 redirect with query parameter "?page=" in urls.py

Tags: django, redirect, django-urls

Have some problem with duplicate pages in Django 1.10.
When the ***urls.py*** had the following code:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^(?P<category_slug>[-\w]+)$', views.category_views, name='cat'),
    ...
]
```

Part of ***views.py***:

```
def category_views(request, category_slug):
    category_name = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
```

Part of ***models.py***:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True, blank=False, verbose_name=u"URL")
```

Pages **site.com/category_slug?page=5** and **site.com/category_slug/?page=5** displayed the same content.

Then I added next redirect in ***urls.py***:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^(?P<category_slug>[-\w]+)$', views.category_views, name='cat'),
    url(r'^(?P<category_slug>[-\w]+)/$', RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='cat', permanent=True)),
    ...
]
```

And now i have redirect from **site.com/category_slug/?page=5** to **site.com/category_slug** (without query parameter), but need to **site.com/category_slug?page=5**

Please tell me where to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As per the docs for 1.10](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview) You can simply add the following keyword argument, `query_string = True`, to your url:

```
url(
    r'^(?P<category_slug>[-\w]+)/$',
    RedirectView.as_view(
        pattern_name='cat', 
        permanent=True,
        query_string=True
    )
 ),
```